# Spyder Console printing in incorrect order

Tags: python, cmd, spyder

```
import sys

def sqrt(x):
   
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError(
            "Cannot compute square root of "
            f"negative number {x}")

    guess = x
    i = 0
    while guess * guess != x and i < 20:
        guess = (guess + x / guess) / 2.0
        i += 1
    return guess


def main():
    try:
        print(sqrt(9))
        print(sqrt(2))
        print(sqrt(-1))
        print("Never get here")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)

    print("Program execution continues normally here.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the above code in a Spyder console I get the following output:

```
'''3.0
1.414213562373095
Program execution continues normally here.
Cannot compute square root of negative number -1'''
```

When I run it from the Windows command prompt I get the following:

```
'''3.0
1.414213562373095
Cannot compute square root of negative number -1
Program execution continues normally here.'''
```

I don't under why the console is printing the last two lines in reverse, can anyone explain?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a problem with the QtConsole not with Spyder. Please also provide us with more information

Comment: Can you give a possible reason as to why this is happening? And more information as in? I have provided a re-usable code.